# Как я могу сделать дефолтное значение в input использую интерполяцию?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне нужно передать дефолтное значение input из той модели, которая у меня находится в data.
Чтобы при рендере там стояло бы значение, которое я бы потом мог поменять.
Нужно max_slippage сделать дефолтным значением. Как мне этого добиться?

```
<teamplate>
 <input class="input border border-gray-400 appearance-none rounded w-full px-3 py-3 pt-5 pb-2 focus focus:border-indigo-600 focus:outline-none active:outline-none active:border-indigo-600" v-model="name" name="inputSlipage" id="slipage" type="text">
{{ max_slippage }}
</template>
<script>
 data() {
   return {
     max_slippage: null,
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начальные значения задаются как обычно в объектном литерале:

```
{
  data() { return {
    name: 'укажи здесь любое начальное значение - оно и окажется в инпуте', 
    max_slippage: 'так же и этому свойству можно указать значение, и любому другому', 
    // .... 
  }}, 
  // .... 
}
```

И никакая интерполяция для этого не нужна.

---

И сразу поясню, что *в функции `data` обратиться к свойствам компонента через `this` **нельзя*** (попытка такого обращения является частой ошибкой новичков) - т.к. эта функция вызывается не в контексте компонента... потому что в момент ее вызова, экземпляр компонента (на который указывал бы `this`) еще не создан.
Обращаться к свойствам компонента можно начиная с `created`/(`onCreated` в Composition API), и в последующих хуках жизненного цикла - подробнее об этом можно прочесть в справке Vue, на ее официальном сайте.

Comment: При таком варианте у меня в дефолтном значении 'some-default-name' стоит

Comment: @yOz, ну да, это естественно и логично - какое указано, такое и будет стоять. А менять значение программно (в методах компонента), можно выражением вида `this.имяСвойства = новоеЗначение;`.

Comment: Да, теперь все понятно, спасибо вам!

Comment: @yOz, не за что, это ведь и в официальной справке Vue написано на первых страницах :)